# google application script cell.setFormulaR1C1

Tags: google-apps-script

How to use  cell.setFormulaR1C1  with absolute references in google Application script using javascript? Something like this - =SUM(A9,$R$4). I would like to do it programatically using the cell.setFormulaR1C1 function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myAbsoluteSum() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
   var myCell = 'A9';
   var myResult = sheet.getRange('B2');
   var myAbsolute = '$R$4';
   myResult.setFormula('=sum('+myCell+','+myAbsolute+')');
}
```

If **myCell** and **myResult** is actually a range, you can create a for loop that changes row/column

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets for relative references, or no brackets for absolute references.

E.g.

- `R1C1` references cell A1
- `R[-1]C[0]` references the cell above the current cell
- `R1C[0]` references the first cell in the current column

Javascript code example to sum the above `n` cells:

```
const n = 10;
range.setFormulaR1C1(`=SUM(R[-1]C:R[-1-${n}]C)`);
```

R1C1 is mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts